# Invalid Syntax over s in mass

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

Im getting an error with line 22 of my code which is 
mass = vac[prop].data[galid,:,0][0]
Invalid syntax over the s in mass

```
binid = vac[2].data
galid = (basic['plate']==str(plate)&(basic['ifudsgn']==str(ifu))
mass = vac[prop].data[galid,:,0][0]
bin1d = vac[4].data[galid,:,0][0]
image_sz = 76
```

Comment: `[galid,:,0]`?? `&`??

Comment: Anyway, missing closing `)` on the `galid = ..` line would be the *first* thing to correct.